# "303 see other" HTTP response in jQuery-bound Virtuemart requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ssl, joomla, virtuemart

Setting up an internet bookstore based on Joomla 2.5.16 CMS and VirtueMart 2.0.24c. My entire site (https://agenty-buduschego.ru) runs on nginx and is using SSL which is forced by enabling rewrite mode in .htaccess file.

The problem is, no Virtuemart functions that use Javascript code (such as adding to cart, filling dropdown with state/province in the user profile, sending email to users from within Virtuemart backend) don't work. VirtueMart uses jQuery 1.6.1 supplied within assets library to do all those vital things.

This is a cross-browser issue.

Below are is an example query and HTTP response headers I'm getting viewed with Firebug in Firefox:

Add to cart GET request:

```
https://agenty-buduschego.ru/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&nosef=1&view=cart&task=addJS&format=json&quantity%3D1%26quantity%255B%255D%3D1%26view%3Dcart%26virtuemart_product_id%255B%255D%3D6%26option%3Dcom_virtuemart&_=1386495981382
```

Request headers:

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Cookie  4eb57c2cab77304872032c29b810ab83=ru-RU; 4eb57c2cab77304872032c29b810ab83=ru-RU; ce03aacdace0d694b35279c3e291619f=4F4313455311+8+75855145914305D50+7445B+55E30+A+4+411114E1642+5414716+94452415C446D555F+144+1+0+252+61019; 192fa9b374f512ee8093cd079b0847d4=eq6n1ih7m80efupendqjhemhb4
Host    agenty-buduschego.ru
Referer https://agenty-buduschego.ru/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=user&layout=edit&lang=ru
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Visually, this produces a hourglass popup in the browser, and with the Firebug, I can view response headers and "**303 see other**" error in jquery.min.js (line 18)

Response headers:

```
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Sun, 08 Dec 2013 09:46:07 GMT
Location    http://agenty-buduschego.ru/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&nosef=1&view=cart&task=addJS&format=json&quantity[0]=1&virtuemart_product_id[0]=6&_=1386495981382&lang=ru
Server  nginx
```

This appears to be connected to SSL enabled on the site, because "303 see other" is told to be a redirect request to the browser to a specified Location, and I can see the "Location" header begins with http://

Another example of non-working JS thing is the empty state/provice dropdown in the user profile, while the following GET appears to complete successfully if pasted directly into the browser's address line:

```
https://agenty-buduschego.ru/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=state&format=json&virtuemart_country_id=176&lang=ru
```

Virtuemart forum hasn't been helpful, I only was advised to investigate my SSL setup, although the problem seems to be widespread among Virtuemart users and every found thread on this breaks with no solution provided.

I suspect that replacing of jQuery library or hacking into VM code might help, but would be thankful for getting any direction to investigate this in depth.

Any ideas?

**UPD:** Got the **Add to Cart** button working by unticking the **Display modal popup upon ‘Add to cart’** box in the Checkout tab of Virtuemart conguration.

It's a partial work-around, though, because other Ajax functions still don't work.

Feeling that the problem needs just one final kick to solve.

Maybe motools scripts are shadowing over jQuery scripts?..

From the header of the User Profile page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/com_virtuemart/assets/js/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/com_virtuemart/assets/js/jquery.noConflict.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/com_virtuemart/assets/js/vmsite.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/com_virtuemart/assets/js/chosen.jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/system/js/mootools-core.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/system/js/core.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/system/js/mootools-more.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/system/js/tabs.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/system/js/validate.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/com_virtuemart/assets/js/vmtabs.js">
```

Comment: I assume that you went with the .htaccess hack because you couldn't get the built-in Joomla "Force SSL" option to work?

Comment: When I tried "Force SSL", it caused endless redirect loop error. .htaccess rewrite rules helped to resolve that everywhere except this jQuery part. The thing got bit more complicated because I chose to use http://agenty-buduschego.ru to be my domain name (without the www part) and bought the SSL certificate for the same (multi-domain cert was more expensive). But Apache still thinks that HTTP_HOST=www.agenty-buduschego.ru and this lead me though the series of customization efforts to make Joomla authorize users and name cookies right.

Comment: However, since I don't see the www part in the "303" redirect URL, this might not be related to the current issue.

Comment: BTW, it was suggested in a similar situation to use jQuery Easy plugin (http://www.simplifyyourweb.com/index.php/downloads/category/8-loading-jquery), but unfortunately, it doesn't have a free version. I'll check if trial version is available.

Comment: We use Joomla's "Force SSL" on most sites, many with JQuery and a few with Virtuemart without any issues. One even has no `www` prefix on the domain. So I have to ask what 'series of customization efforts to make Joomla authorize users and name cookies right' did you do? Also you keep saying `Apache` but the headers you've posted indicate `nginx`.

Comment: You are right, this must be nginx web server, I'll update the question text. I was misguided by the presence of .htaccess file in my dir, didn't know it wasn't exclusively Apache-specific.

Comment: You are right, this must be nginx web server, I'll update the question text. I was misguided by the presence of .htaccess file in my dir, didn't know it wasn't exclusively Apache-specific.

Comment: On my customizations I did to make authorization and cookies respect the actual domain name:  `libraries/joomla/environment/uri.php` line 173 changed `$theURI = 'http' . $https . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` to `$theURI = 'http' . $https . 'agenty-buduschego.ru' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Comment: Next, `\administrator\components\com_virtuemart\helpers\vmview.php`, changed `JUtility::getToken();` to `JHTML::_( 'form.token' );`

Comment: Next, followed the hack advise given at [http://www.jfusion.org/index.php/docs/doku.php?id=fix;joomla_cookie](http://www.jfusion.org/index.php/docs/doku.php?id=fix;joomla_cookie) in `/libraries/joomla/session/session.php`, `/libraries/joomla/application/application.php`, `/plugins/system/remember/remember.php`, `/plugins/system/logout/logout.php`, `/plugins/system/languagefilter/languagefilter.php`

Comment: And finally, in `includes/application.php`, changed line 175 from `$document->setBase(htmlspecialchars(JURI::current()));` to `$document->setBase(htmlspecialchars(JURI::base(false)));`

Comment: Please also see my recent update in the main post.